# Vuetify v-file-input with icon only, vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to add a file input that will open only by clicking on the icon
Only Vuetify2 works (by using hide input ), not Vuetify3
Why is this happening? What should I do when there are so many differences between versions?

<v-file-input
hide-input
truncate-length="15"

> 

Comment: Check the file input API. https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/

Answer (score 0):

**hide-input** is not yet implemented in Vuetify 3. As a workaround, you can use the following:

```html
<template>

<v-file-input class="file-input"/>

<template>

<style scoped>

.file-input:deep().v-input__control,
.file-input:deep().v-input__details {
  display: none;
}

<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create yout own input-file component, like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

interface Props {
  text?: string
  icon?: string
}
withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  text: 'File',
  icon: 'mdi-file',
})

const emit = defineEmits<{
  change: [value: Event]
}>()

const inputFile = ref()

const handleInputFile = () => {
  if (inputFile.value) inputFile.value.click()
}

const uploadAvatar = async (evt: Event) => {
  emit('change', evt)
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn
    :icon="icon"
    @click="handleInputFile"
  >
  </v-btn>
  <v-file-input
    ref="inputFile"
    style="display: none"
    @change="uploadAvatar"
  ></v-file-input>
</template>
```